# How to understand CSS Background-Position coordinates

Tags: css

Every time I create a sprite to use as css background-image, I have to crunch the math and remind myself how to remember the X and the Y coordinates in pixels. How can I remember it or see it visually to keep it straight?

Comment: I usually keep the images anywhere on the Sprite sheet and then check out there co-ordinates by clicking on each graphic element in Fireworks(i use fireworks) and then negating the co-ordinates. For eg:if an element is at x=23px and y=20px, then in the CSS, i use `background-position:-23pz -20px`. This does the work always.

Comment: Believe it or not, I like your solution better than my own. Post it as an answer so I can give you the check

Comment: Hey just dropping by. Sup.Which technique are you using now for getting the coordinates?

Comment: Haven't needed to in a while, but I still think negating the co-ords is the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually keep the images anywhere on the Sprite sheet and then check out there co-ordinates by clicking on each graphic element in Fireworks(i use fireworks) and then negating the co-ordinates. For eg:if an element is at x=23px and y=20px, then in the CSS, i use *`background-position:-23px -20px`*. This always does the work.

Answer (score 12):

I came up with this graphic, hope it's helpful to someone else as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Think 'Y' rhymes with 'SKY' so thats your top measurement (distance in px) from the top. That leaves 'X' as the remaining distance (distance from left in pixels)

When I say distance from left and distance from top, I am referring to the distance in pixels from the side of your overall image to when the part you want to show, begins.

Comment: That's a really cute mnemonic for x,y - I am going to be teaching a Scratch class soon to a bunch of kids and I'll be sure to use it! - is there any particular reason x and y position coordinates start from the left and from the top or is it because we think of application GUIs as starting from that point since the menu options are usually up there? (Kind of unrelated questions...)

Comment: Most things start from 'top left', i'm not sure why. When you build a website, all items will start from stop left unless positioned/stated otherwise. In the western world a lot of subjects have a default starting position of top left, eg reading, writing.

Comment: I didn't even think about reading on a page - that's totally true, and makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Thank you! I'm @`gersandelf` so you'll notice my follow ;)